# Show a button via PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to show the second button when i click on the first button , I've coded this but for an unknown reason it didn't work . hope anyone help me:

```
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="bb1" value="Show Button" "></input>
      <a href="#">
            <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
                 <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['bb1'])){
                     echo "<input class=\"btn btn-success\" type=\"file\" name=\"bb1\" value=\"Show ME\" \"></input>
";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, i just need to add the input inside the form.